# I have whitelisted a file for git, but it still seems to be ignored

Tags: git

My .gitignore contains

```
/artifacts
!/artifacts/read.me
```

The intention is to ignore everything in the directory artifacts, including all of its subdirectories, with the sole exception of `artifacts/read.me`.

Then, I create the read.me file. However, `git status` still does not show `artifacts/read.me` as new (untracked) file. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Found out what's wrong. The first rule should not be

```
/artifacts
```

but

```
/artifacts/*
```